# Converting KML to layer in ArcGIS 10 - nothing happens

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, convert, kml

I have converted many KML files to layer in ArcGIS many times before without any problem.  I just did a conversion (Arc Toolbox>Conversion tools> KML to layer) and the file is showing up in the table of contents but there is no layer. Any ideas or suggestions??
[image]

Comment: is it possible there are no features in the KML? What does it look like in Google Earth?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the layer and choosing "Zoom to extent" (or similar command, I don't remember the exact wording and don't have Arc in front of me now). If you find the data, but offset from where it should be, you may need to set the spatial reference system of your data frame or one of your layers.

Comment: the KML file is a polygon. When I "Zoom to layer" it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I've never worked with a KML layer in ArcMap, but is it a symbology issue? Perhaps it's not appearing correctly against your background.

Comment: if you look at the attributes do you see any features?

Comment: Have you looked at the source?  If so, can you post it here so we can have a look at the geometries?

Comment: Went to Arc Toolbox----Conversion Tools-----From KML To layer. But still l cant come out with it ,wonder what lm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like it was a bug and all I needed to do is download the lastest service pack (SP3) from ESRI. http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1807

Thanks everyone for all the suggestions.

Comment: You can always select your own answer as the accepted answer to the question. It "completes" the QA process when you do (plus you get credit, in the form of points, for solving the issue.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but thought of adding my solution after encountering exactly the same problem as yours and ending up here.

I don't know the exact technicality why the converted KML doesn't show properly in arcgis but if you convert the kml file of the "google earth folder" holding the "specific kml" you want to convert instead of converting directly the "specific kml" file then it shows up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used the KML to Layer (Conversion) tool to create shapefiles from KML files created in Google Earth.

Result was nothing, UNTIL! I went to "Add Data".  After running the tool you'll see a .gdb file with same name as what you thought would be a .shp file.

Select to add that .gdb file and your layer pops right up.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a really old thread but I recently ran into this same issue using ArcMap 10.3 basic. I ran the tool using python within ArcMap and it worked but the tool from the tool box was not working. Here is an arcpy code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'ENTER WORKSPACE PATH'
arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion('INPUTFILENAME.lyr', 'OUTPUTFILENAME.kmz')
```

Comment: are you trying to say that using the python code brought by you solve the issue? Your answer is unclear. Please clarify it using the edit button.

Comment: I can confirm that Rob's solution works for ArcMap 10.2.2. I experienced exactly this problem (April 22nd, 2015), namely the toolbox "Layer To KML" tool produces a KMZ which Google Earth does not display. Using the Python code makes a KMZ which is fine for Google Earth.